# Package does not exist error when trying to start react native project

Tags: android, react-native

When running `npm run android` I get this error while completing the `:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac` task.

```
C:\Users\harry\Documents\Projects\wfd\android\app\src\main\java\uk\co\wfd\MainApplication.java:15: error: package uk.co.wfd.generated does not exist
import uk.co.wfd.generated.BasePackageList;
```

The file does exist and its in the directory `android\app\src\main\java\uk\co\wfd\generated` I've tried running `cd android && ./gradlew clean && ./gradlew :app:bundleRelease` but that hasn't fixed the issue

Comment: chceck MainApplication.java file, your error mean you import uk.co.wfd.generated.BasePackageList; in this file and this file don't exist, if you do it by mistake remove this line

Comment: @AhmedGaber as I said previously, that file does exist

Comment: Ok, try remove this line "import uk.co.wfd.generated.BasePackageList" from MainApplication.java file